# Update object property in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

```
 const [fields, setFields] = useState({
    country: { country: "India" },
    address: { street1: "street1", street2: "street2" },
  });
```

This is my object. I want to update an inner property from this object

```
let id = 'street1'     
let params = { ...fields, [id]: value }; //This will add a new prop
```

[image: Params result]

But i want to update the street1 inside the address object. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```js
const updatedObject = {
  ...fields,
  address: {
    ...fields.address,
    [id]: value,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{...fields,address:{...fields.address,"street1":"abc"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let userAddress = {
    country: { country: "India" },
    address: { street1: "street1", street2: "street2" },
};
```

I believe the situation is to update the value of object that is nested , in this case street1.

Best way with ES6 would be to destructure and update the value.

```
userAddress = {
    ...userAddress,
    address: { ...state.address, street1: newValue },
};
```